# Failing to try to change an image when keypressed

Tags: java, animation, keyevent

I'm trying to make it so when I press down the right key a new picture pops up making it look like my character is walking, not quite sure how to do that though... Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;


public class Dude {
    int x, dx, y;
    Image still;

    public Dude() {
            ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("Ken3.png");
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("KenTurn1.png");
            still = i.getImage();
            x = 50;
            y = 785;
    }


    public void move() {
            x = x + dx;
    }

    public int getX() {
            return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
            return y;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
            return still;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
                    dx = -2;

            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) 
                    dx = 2;

            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
                dx = 5;

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
                    dx = 0;

            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
                    dx = 0;
```

Any help would be awesome thanks!

Comment: Simple way that fits in a comment: Make an array of images, then when you press a key it adds one to the array index hence changing the picture.

Comment: @ns47741, i'm new to java, don't know how to do that yet.

Answer (score 0):

something like this, i commented it. Good luck

```
public class Dude {

    private int walkingIndex;
    private Image walkingFrames;
    private Image still;

    private String state;

    public Dude() {
        // say were starting off standing
        state = "standing";
        // init our still frame
        still = (new ImageIcon("Ken3.png")).getImage();

        // set our walking frame to 0 to start
        walkingIndex = 0;
        walkingFrames = new Image[3]; // or however many images you have in your walking animation
        // go through each frame and initialize the image to KenWalking{index}.png
        for(int i=0;i<walkingFrames.length;i++) {
            walkingFrames[i] = (new ImageIcon("KenWalking"+i+".png")).getImage();
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        x+=dx;
        // add 1 to the walking index and make sure its not greater than our number of walking frames, % means get the remainder of
        // so 12 % 10 = 2, and 8 % 7 = 1
        walkingIndex = (walkingIndex+1)%walkingFrames.length;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        // if our state is walking then give out a walking frame
        if(state.equals("walking")) {
            return walkingFrames[walkingIndex];
        } else {
            // otherwise we can assume were standing, so show that image instead
            return still;
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        ... same stuff
        state = "walking";
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        ... same stuff
        state = "standing";
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, I copied it exactly, however the 'walking' , 'standing' and length (in this walkingIndex = (walkingIndex+1)%walkingFrames.length;) have errors in them. Error says "invalid character constant" in 'standing' and 'walking' ... length says "length cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question right, you are looking for a keyListener. In that case, you can do two things. Add keybindings or add an KeyListener. 
Please have in mind that i haven't tested the code on your template, it work well for me in an AWT frame. Hope it helps

First implement the EventListener to Dude

```
public class Dude implements KeyListener{ ...
```

For the KeyListener to work you must have a focusable component..

```
    component.addKeyListener(this);
    component.setFocusable(true);
    component.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
```

The method below will be implemented with the KeyListener

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int x = e.getKeyCode();

    switch(x){
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            // Do Your stuff
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            // Do Your stuff
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            // Do Your stuff
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            // Do Your stuff
            break;
    }
}
```